# How do I know what my offense level is?

Tags: steam, counter-strike-global-offensive

I played CS:GO a few times a while ago, but I got kicked frequently (because of my internet connection) and every time I do something wrong I get a 7 day ban.

The one thing I don't know is what level of offense I am in CS:GO.
I already know that the level of offense can go higher than level 4 as that is a 7 day ban.
So I wanted to know, because I know my level is over level 4, where can I see which level of offense I am?

Comment: What do you mean 'level of offence' Is this only on one server?

Comment: its on competitive matches

Comment: Oh I know what's wrong

Comment: and what is it?

Comment: made an answer as it was too lengthy for a comment :)

Answer (score 1):

Because you keep getting kicked from the competitive servers, there is a penalty for quitting a competitive server before the end of a match. It means that you cannot play any more matches for a while and I believe that that time increases after so many times.

Stick to `Play against bots offline` or to normal matches until your internet can keep you connected.

> During a cooldown period, a player cannot play any competitive matchmaking, but can still play any of the casual game modes, including community servers or locally-hosted servers running the competitive rule set. Cooldown levels drop by 1 level after a week with no additional offenses. There is no known limit to how many levels a person can get.
>
> Level 1 - 30 minutes
>
> Level 2 - 2 hours
>
> Level 3 - 24 hours
>
> Level 4 - 7 days
>
> Level 5 - This is given by [**Overwatch**](http://counterstrike.wikia.com/wiki/VAC) and the time varies

Comment: yes i know that. but i can have the minimal bann time again if i dont get kicked for a certain time. and i just need to know my level of offense.

Comment: because if im (for exemple) 12 i know i need to wait 12 weeks to be in level 1 again

Comment: it says: Cooldown levels drop by 1 level after a week with no additional offenses.

Comment: but if im level 12 i need to wait 12 weeks right?

Comment: No, look at the time list your ban is 7 days right?

Comment: yes but i have been banned for 7 days more then once

Comment: Ok so now do not connect to any competitive servers for I would say about 5 weeks now, just play normal matches and against bots. Then if your internet is good enough and only then, try and play a competitive match.

Comment: Have I answered your question @Francisco ?

Comment: @Skye No begging for accepts, that's highly discouraged on this site.

Comment: @kappagasm he's hardly begging for an accept in that last comment. However, if a previous comment was deleted then your comment is obsolete.

Comment: sry only have internet connection now...

Comment: ok, just one last thing. where can i see my offense level? i know the other part because of you guys (thx btw) but if idk my offense level idk how many weeks i have to wait...

Comment: You can't, when was the last time you where banned and for how long?